# Show posts on my WebSite from Facebook's wall

Tags: facebook

I'm building my website and what I am trying to do is the following:
I'd like to show the recent post I've made on my facebook's wall on my webpage, but just my own post not everyone else's just mine!

Here's an example of how I would like to do it:
[image: facebookwall post example]

I have done the same with twitter which is very simple: setting---> widget----> create new widget---> and that's it!

But in facebook I have tried with developers tools (comments plugin)in facebook but that's not what I need because it shows everyones post, it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is very simple as go to [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/), and in the Facebook page URL, you just have to change that URL for yours, like this:

http://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers

Change it to:

http://www.facebook.com/yourfanpageID

Then just check "show post" and then "get code"and that's it.  You will finally show your post in your website page.